# Understanding Optionals.orElse

Tags: java, null, java-8, option-type, notnull

I am trying to learn **Java 8 feature Optional**. I am confused about how Optional.orElse is working. Here is what i have tried:

```
public class OptionalsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Name userName = new Name();
        userName.setName("John Doe");
        Optional<Name> optionalName = Optional.ofNullable(userName);
        optionalName.ifPresent(
                (Name value) -> {
                    Optional<String> optionalNameString = Optional.ofNullable(value.getName());
                    optionalNameString.ifPresent(name -> System.err.println("Name is: " + optionalNameString.get()));
                }
        );
    }
    private static void printError() {
        System.err.println("No Name present");
    }
}
```

My Concern is that if name is set everything works fine but when no name is set i want to execute **orElse**. 
I want to do something when i comment

```
userName.setName("John Doe");
```

like printing No Name Found

How can i do that?

TIA

Comment: When you write `optionalNameString.ifPresent(name -> …)`, the actual `String` is already provided in the `name` parameter, so it makes no sense to invoke `get()` on the `optionalNameString` within the lambda expression. Similarly, it wouldn’t make any sense to invoke `orElse` at this place as the lambda expression won’t get executed when the `Optional` is empty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your usage of nested `ifPresent` calls is very similar to the (nested) `forEach` calls on streams, seen in a lot of other questions.

They are a clear sign that you should try better on functional thinking.

What you want to do is

```
System.out.println(
    Optional.ofNullable(userName) // will be an empty optional if userName is null
            .map(Name::getName)   // will turn to empty optional if getName returns null
            .map("Name is: "::concat) // prepend "Name is: " (only when we have a name)
            .orElse("No Name Found") // get the result string or the alternative
    );
```

The important point to understand, is, that the `map`ping steps applied to an empty `Optional` don’t do anything but return an empty `Optional` again. Since you want to print in either case, the print statement is not passed as consumer, but written as stand-alone statement, printing the value returned by the `orElse` invocation, which will be either, the non-`null` result of the processing steps or the alternative `String`.

Comment: @hogler m starting it , never too late ;) Thank you for explaination

Comment: Very useful: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/java8-optional.html

Answer (score -1):

The orElse method allows you to return an alternative value when there isn't one in the Optional.

If you just want to print out an alternative String you can use the orElse method to return an alternative String:

```
Optional<String> optionalNameString = Optional.ofNullable(value.getName());
System.out.println(optionalNameString.orElse("Name is not present"));
```

Otherwise you can just check if the value is present using isPresent()

```
Optional<String> optionalNameString = Optional.ofNullable(value.getName());
if(optionalNameString.isPresent()) {
    // do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of Optional if we r using ifs :p

Comment: @sector11 it avoids NPEs